# React Native / Using strings as data in FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a JSON with the following shape for ~50 _source entries:

```
   {
"hits": [
    {
        "_source": {
            "name": "henry",
            "jobs": ["judge", "lawyer"]
        }
    },
    {
        "_source": {
            "name": "henry",
            "jobs": ["dev", "waitress"]
        }
    }
    // ...
]
}
```

Thanks to the community's help, I extracted each jobs as below:

```
const result = hits.reduce((acc, item) => acc = [item._source.jobs[0], ...acc], []) 

console.log(result) // this is an array
```

I extracted each item from result to add a string (for example "welcome judge"):

```
  for(i in result)   
        { 
          var message = 'welcome'+ result[i] //this is a string              
        }
```

So now, I want to use a flatlist to render my message:

```
 constructor() {
   super()
   this.state = { dataSource:'' }
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch('uri')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => { 
   const result = hits.reduce((acc, item) => acc = [item._source.jobs[0], ...acc], []) // this is an array
   for(i in result)   
    { 
      var message = 'welcome'+ result[i] //this is a string              
    }
    this.setState({ dataSource : messsage})
}

renderItem =({item}) => {
return( 
<View>     
  <Text>item</Text>
</View>)
}


render() {  
return (
  <View>
      <FlatList 
        data= {[this.state.dataSource]}
        renderItem= {this.renderItem}
      /> 
  </View>      
);
}
```

I got only one message (and not my list) and the warning 'missing key for item'

Comment: `dataSource` should be an array. An you are overriding each time that value with `message` var. Adding each message to array using push and later use the `setState`

Answer (score 0):

You should have `keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}` in your flatlist.

```
<FlatList 
   data= {[this.state.dataSource]}
   keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
   renderItem= {this.renderItem}
/>
```

Here is a [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#keyextractor) keyExtractor definition.

Answer (score 0):

**You will only get a single message, because your input data is just a string** (converted to an array in render() to fit specifications). You change your single string variable in every iteration and update with the last changed one. You do need to push every string into an array, before you continue to the next item in the Iterable.

```
constructor() {
   super()
   this.state = { dataSource: [] }
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch('uri')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => { 

   // Get all jobs in a single array
   const results = hits.reduce((acc, item) => acc = [item._source.jobs[0], ...acc], []);

   // Iterate over results, concatenate with 'welcome' and push into a new array
   let messages = [];
   for(i in result)   
    { 
      let message = 'welcome'+ result[i];
      messages.push(message);             
    }

    // Update state with the new array 'messages'
    this.setState({ dataSource : messages })
}

renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return( 
    <View>     
      <Text>{item}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


render() {  
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList 
        data={this.state.dataSource}
        keyExtractor={(x, i) => i.toString()}
        renderItem= {this.renderItem}
      /> 
    </View>      
  );
}
```

Comment: Check whether your fetch returns a valid list. You can also log the state after setState is called. 

And set item inside curly braces {item]...Ive updated my answer

Comment: I did everything. My list is valid. I have an array of strings

Comment: It's hard to help without having access to your updated code. Can u maybe share a snack?

Answer (score 0):

Because your data source contains single string. Here you are updating the message var on each iteration, so it will have just the last string of the result array with 'hello' prepended.

```
for(i in result)   
        { 
          var message = 'welcome'+ result[i]
```

}

You should do something like this

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('uri')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => { 
           const result = hits.reduce((acc, item) => acc = [item._source.jobs[0], ...acc], [])
           let messages=[];
           for(i in result)   
            { 
              messages.push('welcome '+ result[i]); //push each element in array             
            }
           this.setState({ dataSource : messsages})
        }
```

Use key extractor to remove missing key warning

```
render() {  
return (
  <View>
      <FlatList 
        data= {[this.state.dataSource]}
        renderItem= {this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      /> 
  </View>      
);
}
```